# Integrate Edge Extensions into a Webview UWP from microsoft store

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I'm making a simple browser (that can call command line tools) with Webview UWP.
I want to know if it's possible to install pre-made extensions since Webview use the Edge render.
I found this about extensions in webview:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/extensions/webview

But I don't really know if this is just for extensions made by developers and I don't understand how to use it (there is no example).

Maybe it's not even possible, if that's the case I just want to know so that I can give up.
If possible I would like to get a sample code of the xaml and the C# part, just some tips to understand it better.

Comment: It's impossible. There is no relationship between the webview extension and the 'pre-made extensions'.